# Dalvik format failed: Failed to convert dex. PermGen space- Android

Tags: android, machine-learning, weka

i need to use a classifier J48 in android. But running into heapspace problems. Is there a way to fix the same? I get an error that states. Dalvik format failed: Failed to convert dex. PermGen space.

Comment: *But running into heapspace problems* .... which problems?

Comment: Your second question is not suitable for this site. I suggest you split your question into two separate questions. The first question you can post here , but the second one isn't really the sort of question that has a correct answer. You should ask the second one on some other site where it would be more relevant there.

Comment: @Cristian...have written the "problems"
@Mark Byers... could you please suggest some other site to ask that sort of a question. thanks
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a memory problem using J48 in Weka on android.
I would try to diagnose this in the following order:

1. How much memory does your program consume? See [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Can+I+check+how+much+memory+is+available+for+WEKA%3F) and [here](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/26708-out-memory-error.html#post109519) for Weka memory consumption.
2. Add more memory to the JVM (also in the earlier links).
3. Try running this on a more affluent JVM - can this run on a desktop? Or is the problem unrelated to the OS resources?
4. Tune your algorithm - build a smaller tree or prune it more heavily.
5. Prune your dataset - remove unnecessary attributes.
6. Prune your dataset - use fewer instances.
7. Use a different algorithm.
8. If all else fails - implement your decision tree using a different library (scipy/Orange/KNIME/Rapid miner), or roll your own.